# Showing Azure WebJob Functions log using API (Kudu)

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, kudu

I am using Kudu Api to display some webjob data on a website monitoring app I created. The web app monitors data from a few other websites I created. I was wondering what API endpoints do I need to run in order to get the data from this page:

**https://{my_website}.scm.azurewebsites.net/azurejobs/#/functions**

I am interested in displaying some of the data from this page (functions, statistics, Invocation Log - Recently executed functions)

At the moment I am parsing a text file, but I find this highly inefficient if there's a better option available:

**https://{my_website}.scm.azurewebsites.net/vfs/data/jobs/continuous/{my_webjob}/job_log.txt**

Any suggestions would help, thanks in advance.

Comment: https://<sitename>.scm.azurewebsites.net/azurejobs/api/functions/definitions?limit=100 could be a possiblity

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Regardless to what I'm passing in as a limit parameter (even if I pass in 2 instead of 100) I am getting the following error: **{"message":"The request is invalid.","modelState":{"limit":["The field Limit must be between 1 and 100."]}}** and if I try **https://<sitename>.scm.azurewebsites.net/azurejobs/api/functions/definitions** I get **{"message":"An error has occurred."}** which isn't telling me much. Also, I cannot seem to find any documentation for this api bit you mentioned.

Comment: I didn't look up documentation i just assumed that the javascript client on the webjobs scm site used a well documented API.

The javascript client passes 10 to the limit parameter, i just took a quick look in the kudu source but cant seem to find the code for this API call maybe you are more successful:
https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't realize it was printed in the browser's console. These are the endpoints I needed. The definitions endpoint worked this time (not sure why it didn't in the first place): **https://<sitename>.scm.azurewebsites.net/azurejobs/api/functions/invocations/recent?limit=90
https://<sitename>.scm.azurewebsites.net/azurejobs/api/functions/definitions?limit=11** Can you post this as an answer so that I can accept it? Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As written in comments the WebJob client is javascript based you can see every call it makes in the console of your browser, there you will find a call to:

```
https://<sitename>.scm.azurewebsites.net/azurejobs/api/functions/definitions?lim‌​it=100
```

This give a list of the functions in the webjob.